# ldd & shared object error Linux - how to troubleshoot?

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, ldd

I'd like to learn how to troubleshoot the following error:

```
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgis-3.so": /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/libproj.so.15)
```

Related:

```
$ ldd /usr/pgsql-11/lib/postgis-3.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffdd426000)
    libgeos_c.so.1 => /usr/local/lib/libgeos_c.so.1 (0x00007f2937933000)
    libproj.so.15 => /usr/local/lib/libproj.so.15 (0x00007f293744d000)
    libjson-c.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libjson-c.so.2 (0x00007f2937242000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f2936ed8000)
    libz.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f2936cc2000)
    libm.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f29369c0000)
    libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f29367bc000)
    libSFCGAL.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libSFCGAL.so.1 (0x00007f2935cf9000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f293592b000)
    libgeos-3.8.1.so => /usr/local/lib/libgeos-3.8.1.so (0x00007f2935558000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/local/lib/../lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f293517f000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/local/lib/../lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f2934f67000)
    libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007f2934c4a000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f2934a2e000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f2934808000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2937e73000)
    libCGAL.so.11 => /usr/lib64/libCGAL.so.11 (0x00007f29345e0000)
    libCGAL_Core.so.11 => /usr/lib64/libCGAL_Core.so.11 (0x00007f29343a7000)
    libmpfr.so.4 => /usr/lib64/libmpfr.so.4 (0x00007f293414c000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f2933ed4000)
    libboost_date_time-mt.so.1.53.0 => /usr/lib64/libboost_date_time-mt.so.1.53.0 (0x00007f2933cc3000)
    libboost_thread-mt.so.1.53.0 => /usr/lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so.1.53.0 (0x00007f2933aac000)
    libboost_system-mt.so.1.53.0 => /usr/lib64/libboost_system-mt.so.1.53.0 (0x00007f29338a8000)
    libboost_serialization-mt.so.1.53.0 => /usr/lib64/libboost_serialization-mt.so.1.53.0 (0x00007f293363c000)
    librt.so.1 => /usr/lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f2933434000)
```

Also:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib64:/usr/lib64
```

When I compiled Postgis the target was /usr/local so I'm puzzled why the error mentions /lib64/libstdc++.so.6

Any pointers or help would be appreciated, I'd like to understand what else I should try/do.

Comment: So `/usr/local/lib/libproj.so.1` was compiled with newer glibc, but at runtime it links to the system one. In CentOS you simply don't do such things, it is an enterprise system despite being a community one as well. Compile your library against system libraries / create RPM package instead.

Comment: Thanks Danila, but some software we use needs to be built with a newer version of gcc. Is there really not a way to overcome this snafu? This is the first time I've encountered this error, after many years of happy users. Can you please elaborate on how to compile against system libraries/create RPM package instead?